# Why does my Minesweeper clone count the neighboring bombs inaccurately?

Tags: python-3.x, minesweeper

I am writing a Minesweeper clone in Python 3 that runs in the terminal window. The minefield is represented by a 10x10 array:

```
minefield = [[0 for i in range(LENGTH)] for j in range(HEIGHT)]
```

20 mines are placed into `minefield` and an example is shown below. Bombs are denoted by -1.

```
 0-1-1-1 0 0 0-1-1 0
 0 0 0-1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0-1 0-1-1-1 0 0 0-1
 0 0 0 0 0-1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0-1 0 0-1 0-1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0-1 0 0
 0 0-1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-1 0-1
```

Both the functions `place_numbers()` and `count_neighbours(a, b)` work on the global 10x10 array minefield. `count_neighbours(a, b)` takes an element`minefield[a][b]` and counts the neighbouring bombs in the 8 squares around it. This function is returning incorrect values.

```
def place_numbers():
    global minefield
    for i in range(0, LENGTH):
        for j in range(0, HEIGHT):
            if minefield[i][j] != -1:
                neighbours = count_neighbours(i, j)
                minefield[i][j] = neighbours
    print("Bombs placed!!")
    pretty_print(minefield)


@staticmethod
def count_neighbours(a, b):
    neighbours = 0
    for i in (a-1, a, a+1):
        for j in (b-1, b, b+1):
            if i != a and j != b: # we do not need to count the square itself whose neighbours we're counting
                if i in range(0, 10) and j in range(0, 10): # to check if the square is within bounds
                    if minefield[i][j] == -1: #neighbour at i, j located
                        neighbours += 1
    return neighbours
```

The output of the code after counting the neighbouring bombs in the above example is given below.

```
 0-1-1-1 1 0 0-1-1 0
 2 1 4-1 3 1 2 1 2 1
 0-1 1-1-1-1 1 0 0-1
 1 0 2 2 2-1 2 0 3 0
 0 0 0 0-1 0 2-1 1-1
 0 1 0 2 0 1 1-1 2 0
 0 0-1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 2 0
-1 0-1 0 0 0 0-1 0-1
```

`count_neighbours(a, b)` iterates through the 8 squares around [a, b] except itself. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change this line:

```
if i != a and j != b:
```

to

```
if i != a or j != b:
```

Consider `a = 3, b = 3`. Your code will not run if `i = 3, j = 2`. Because the `and` condition will be false. You want it to run when one of the pairs are not equal.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Because of the ```and``` condition, only the neighboring corner squares were being counted, and not the ones in line with ```[a][b]```.

Comment: Given that this is Python, perhaps it is more understandable to write `if (i, j) != (a, b):`.